# What happens to running threads after forking?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, odoo

I'm using OpenERP, a Python based ERP, which uses different threads (one-thread per client, etc). I would like to use multiprocessing.Process() to fork() and call a long-running method.

My question is: what will happen to the parent's threads? Will they be copied and continue to run? Will the child process call accept() on the server socket?

Thanks for your answers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forking does not copy threads, only the main one. So *be very careful* with forking multithreaded application as it can cause unpredictable side-effects (e.g when forking happened while some thread was executing in a mutexed critical section), something really can be broken in your forked process unless you know the code you're forking ideally.

Though everything that I said above is true, there's a workaround (at least on Linux) called pthread_atfork() which acts as a callback when a process was forked (you can recreate all needed threads). Though it applies to C applications, it's not applied to Python ones.

For further information you can refer to:

- Python issue tracker on this problem - http://bugs.python.org/issue6923
- Seek around the web on similar ideas implementation, for example: http://code.google.com/p/python-atfork/

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, if the parent's threads are no copied in the child, why would this be a problem ? Parent's threads continue to execute themself in the parent, and in the child I can run my function which do some basic job. Could you provide an example of problem that might occurs ? Thank you.

Comment: @ThibautD. Let's look at the example. You have a dict in memory that holds some application state. Your thread sets a lock, changes that dict (e.g. changing some values of the dict's keys) and releases that lock. Within a time frame the dict is locked, it has an inconsistent (broken) state (some changes are made and some are still waiting to apply). And in this horrible moment you fork your process. Result: you receive broken state.