# safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic

Tags: python, multiprocessing, documentation

source:https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

I am reading python documentation for multiprocessing and noticed sentence

> Note that safely forking a multithreaded process is problematic.

wondering if I am not getting it right OR how would it be problematic?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820248/what-happens-to-running-threads-after-forking/12820303).

Comment: Forking a multithreaded process is a general problem not just specific to python. [Here's](http://www.doublersolutions.com/docs/dce/osfdocs/htmls/develop/appdev/Appde193.htm) a decent explanation.